# Flutter Why tz.TZDatetime gives the device time?

Tags: flutter, timezone, flutter-test

I want to get the time right now in cairo but the timezone package give me the device date why ?

```
DateTime returnCommonDate(){
tz.initializeTimeZones();
final egyptTimeZone = 
tz.getLocation('Africa/Cairo');
final now = 
tz.TZDateTime.now(egyptTimeZone);
print"his is egypt time ${now}");
return now;
```

}

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.  Follow up in comments on your original question instead.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the toLocal() function of the "timezone" package:

tz.TZDateTime.now(egyptTimeZone).toLocal()

Comment: not working , it still give me the device datetime

Comment: @khaledmohamed maybe, this package do not support Egypt. Try a different package. There are a bundle of other packages that you can use for Egypt timezone.

Comment: Do u recommend any other package ?